# Theme edit - only directions or file names needed

Tags: php, cms, ce-1.9.1.0, footer

Ok. At start i must say, this is a few things i need to do but i can't find it. Please, write answers with numbers, this is gonna be really helpful. Ok, lets start.

**1)Shopview - right bar**

a)I want to remove Last vieved (Ostatnio oglądane produkty) and My orders (Moje zamówienia)-red ring

b)I want to remove Paypal option on homepage = blue ring[image]

**2)Footer** - I want to remove ad from theme creator (i cant do it from magento admin page)[image]

**3)Cart**

a)I want to remoove Paypal option from here (Paypal must stay only in checkout options) and this field - red rings

b)I want to move promotion codes to the left side of page -  blue ring[image]

**4)Product page** - Remove paypal too from here[image]

Thats all, i know, this is a lot of this small stupid things, but i have a vision of my shop - easy and evrything should be visible. I hope i get help here, because this forum is awesome and without it a will be stuck on instaling magento. Thanks a lot from above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to some work at layout xml file:

**Shopview - right bar:**

`Create local.xml` at app/design/frontend/`your package/your template/local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
 <default>
    <remove name="topCart.extra_actions" />
    <remove name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: And what i should put into that local.xml? I know how to edit files but don't know how to made from zero.

Comment: Ok. i did it, but it don't works. Nothing happens after refresh cache and reindex.

Comment: It appears after login.

Comment: hey are you need any help on this regards